# Dropdown menu to clicking outside close of Angular 8

Tags: html, angular

Hii I'm using `click` function on `p` tag,

When user opens the dropdown menu, on click outside close the dropdown in angular

Html code

```
<div class="select_cat">
   <p class="cat_name" (click)="openCategoriesList()"> </p>
</div>
<div class="categories_list" *ngIf="openCategories">
   <ul *ngFor="let category of categories"> 
      <span class="title">{{category.group_name}}
      </span> 
      <li *ngFor="let categoryData of category.categories" (click)="categoryClick(categoryData)"> 
      </li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Html code

 <div class="select_cat">
        <p class="cat_name" (click)="openCategoriesList()">
        </p>

      </div>




      <div class="categories_list" *ngIf="openCategories">
        <ul *ngFor="let category of categories">
          <span class="title">{{category.group_name}}</span>
          <li *ngFor="let categoryData of category.categories" (click)="categoryClick(categoryData)">
           
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>

Comment: Can you provide the code you have written or provide a minimal example fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (document:click) event:

**.html code**

```
<div class="select_cat" #paraDiv> /* Created a reference here */
   <p class="cat_name" (click)="openCategoriesList()">Open CategoryList</p>
</div>
<div class="categories_list" *ngIf="openCategories">
   <ul *ngFor="let category of categories"> 
      <span class="title">{{category.group_name}}
      </span> 
      <li *ngFor="let categoryData of category.categories" (click)="categoryClick(categoryData)"> 
      </li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

**.ts code**

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'onDocumentClick($event)',
  }
})

@ViewChild('paraDiv', {static: false}) paraDiv;

onDocumentClick(event) {
   if (!this.paraDiv.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) { // outside click
     this.openCategories = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gangadhar, I'm using multiple checkboxes in formarray for reactive forms how to reset the value after submit

Answer (score 0):

```
 <mat-select #mySelect placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>

   import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect;
  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  click() {
    this.mySelect.open();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Akash, clickout fucntion where do use in html page

Comment: I think now it's easy

Comment: Sry I want using click function is P tag this type of, 

When user is open the dropdown men, to click outside close the dropdown in angular

Comment: call close function as same

Comment: Hi Akash has a small doubt pls suggest to me